# Reuse of fragment contains dialog with hardcoded id in elements

Tags: fragment, sapui5

I'm developing an application in Sapui5 and I have the need to be able to open fragment which contains dialog and inside i have a button with specific Id,
after I close the fragment and try to open it again I get duplicate Id error.
I can't use the most popular solution with the condition that if the fragment exists don't create it again because on the same element i need to be able to open two different fragmants (not on the same time)

i tried destroy,destroyContent,delete,undefined and nothing works,
eventually I ran on all the elements in the dialog and destroy them by Id,

is there any other way to destroy the content of the dialog?

thanks

Comment: Please structure your question in such way that first will be easy to understand to people who might help you, and second it will help people who have the same problem in a future.

Comment: Why do you need a specific ID??

Comment: the entire app is written around it, to change it means to change a lot of things in the app.

Answer (score -1):

The dialog has some methods to handle that like 'destroyButtons()', [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Dialog%23methods/Summary) check the API. 
Normally it's good to close and destroy the dialog after the user pressed 'closed' and just create the dialog again if you want to open the dialog.

```
 this._oDialog.close();
 this._oDialog.destroy();
```